# Bash wildcard in a makefile not working

Tags: bash, makefile

I have this makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash -f

working : 
    if [ -d ffprob_runfail ]; then echo "gotcha" ;fi

error : 
    if [ -d ffprob_* ]; then echo "gotcha" ;fi
```

Executing 'make working' in a folder where the subdirectory 'ffprob_runfail' exists echoes:

> if [ -d ffprob_runfail ]; then echo "gotcha" ;fi
>
> gotcha

Executing 'make error' in the same folder echoes:

> if [ -d ffprob_* ]; then echo "gotcha" ;fi

I am not sure where this 'surprising' behavior comes from - either miscoding in make or bash syntax. I tried escaping * but did not work. Might be an issue with the syntax of [ ] bash operator? (I am quite new to bash, after 20 years of csh pain...)

Any hint appreciated.

### POST EDIT:

Not only the -f option disables globbing (thanks @choroba), but also the -d operator in bash is unary, and cannot used safely with globbing, i.e. refer to [Bash Shell Script: confirm the existance of one or more directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653300/bash-shell-script-confirm-the-existance-of-one-or-more-directories).

So this looks to be the right way (continuation of the previous makefile...):

```
right : 
    for item in ffprob_* ; do if [ -d "$$item" ] ; \
    then echo "gotcha $$item";fi;done
```

Comment: Note that nothing in the Makefile you show even *requires* `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-f` option for bash means the same as the `-f` option to `set`, namely

> `-f`  Disable file name generation (globbing).

With globbing disabled, wildcards aren't expanded.

So, why do you set the shell to `bash -f`? Remove the `-f`.

Comment: Thanks... Er, '-f' comes from my csh background (not loading some startup files for quicker execution).

Comment: I confirm this works. However, if the folder contains more than one subdir satisfying the wildcard, I get an error: >/bin/bash: line 0: [: ffprob_runfail: binary operator expected

Comment: Sure, because the glob is expanded to several filenames, and `-d` expects just one argument.

Comment: Very little `csh` applies to `bash`

Comment: @cdarke: Fortunately!